# Multiple joins in SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, join, select

To clear things up, I have two tables, `employees` and `jobs`.

In `employees` I have columns firstname, lastname, employees id.

In `jobs` I have columns

```
job_id, job_name, job_description, job_opener, job_responsible_person
```

where the last two are foreign keys which refer to the `employees` table.

This is my SQL statement

```
String cmd = "SELECT je.id, firstname, lastname, job_name FROM jat.employees je" +
            " INNER JOIN jat.jobs jj ON je.id = jj.job_opener ";
```

And I fill data table with it.

What I need is adding two more columns, like second first name and second last name, in same table, but which will depend on job_responsible_p, so ON clause would be

```
ON je.id = jj.job_responsible_p
```

Is that possible in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can join several table at once:

```
SELECT je.id, je.firstname, je.lastname, jj.job_name, jr.firstname, jr.lastname
FROM jat.employees AS je INNER JOIN jat.jobs AS jj INNER JOIN jat.employees AS jr
ON je.id=jj.job_opener AND jr.id=jj.job_responsible_person;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is since you can use conditional operator like `AND` `OR` with `JOIN ON` condition.

```
INNER JOIN jat.jobs jj 
ON je.id=jj.job_opener 
AND je.id=jj.job_responsible_p
```